# pyinstaller <project> not including google.cloud.speech_v1

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyinstaller, python-3.7, google-cloud-speech

When I do pyinstaller it executes successfully for python 3.7.
But when I execute the resulting exe I get the result under.
How can I correct this?

```
    dist>mainlocal.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SpeechChangerLocal\mainlocal.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\home\gitrep\ttt\local\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\home\gitrep\ttt\local\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\gapic\speech_client.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-speech' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[2900] Failed to execute script mainlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

I imported google-cloud-speech_v1 instead of google-cloud-speech. Now it works.
I found ["When Things Go Wrong"](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html) in manual very informative: